# WebService iPhone problem parameter library wsdl2objc and SudzC

Tags: objective-c, web-services, jboss, xcode, sudzc

I have a big problem using webservices and iPhone.
I try to user different library : wsdl2objc and SudzC and i have the same problem.

I general my stubs, no problem and when i call webservices methods with parameters my server don't get the parameters.
My server is a JBoss server and wsdl is in Java.

My code with wsdl2objc :

```
MobileActionsBinding *binding = [[MobileActionsBeanService MobileActionsBinding] retain];
MobileActionsBeanService_getListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationId *menu = [[MobileActionsBeanService_getListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationId alloc] init];
    NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:15];
    menu.arg0 = number;

    NSLog(@"menu.arg0 : %@",menu.arg0);
    MobileActionsBindingResponse *response = [binding getListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationIdUsingGetListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationId:menu];

    NSArray *arrayReponse = response.bodyParts;
    for(id bodypart in arrayReponse) {
        if([bodypart isKindOfClass:[MobileActionsBeanService_getListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationIdResponse class]]) {
            MobileActionsBeanService_getListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationIdResponse *appResponse = (MobileActionsBeanService_getListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationIdResponse *)bodypart;

        }

        if([bodypart isKindOfClass:[SOAPFault class]]) {
            SOAPFault *soapFault = (SOAPFault *)bodypart;
            NSLog(@"%@",soapFault.simpleFaultString);
        }
    }
```

My code with SudzC :

```
SDZMobileActionsBeanService *service = [SDZMobileActionsBeanService service];
service.logging = YES;
[service getListMobileMenuItemByMobileApplicationId:self action:@selector(getApp:) arg0:15];
```

In two methods JBoss get arg0 = null

Comment: The NSLog() on the first chunk of code returns the correct value for arg0? Or does it already show (null) ?